# How can I hide my bitcoin transactions to protect anonymity from others?

Tags: privacy

Please take a look at this transaction link of bitcoin :
https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/blablablabla

My bitcoin address is :  `blablablabla`
You can see all of my transactions by this link :
https://www.blockchain.com/btc/address/blablablabla

My friend address is :  `bc1qhkshfzwzm6cl8ezsg5fw7yhpsdqtp4r3vfzzzz`
But you can't see all of his transactions by this link :
https://www.blockchain.com/btc/address/bc1qhkshfzwzm6cl8ezsg5fw7yhpsdqtp4r3vfzzzz

---

What is this address : `bc1qhkshfzwzm6cl8ezsg5fw7yhpsdqtp4r3vfzzzz`
And why is it undetectable?
How can i hide my transactions from others like that address?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your address is a classical `1` (Pay-to-public-key-hash) address. Your friend has a newer [Bech32](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/74791/what-the-difference-between-old-segwit-3-and-new-segwit-address-bc/74792#74792) Pay-to-Witness-public-key-hash-type address. The block explorer you referenced is partially compatible with Bech32. Sometimes, it doesn't work. On the other hand, there's nothing that prevents you from looking at your friend's transactions using a different block explorer such as https://Blockstream.info or https://blockchair.com/.

Answer (score 4):

Bitcoin is not yet built with a privacy layer, all transactions are public and immutable, meaning they are visible to everyone, everywhere, forever.

If you wish to make a private transaction, you are better off using another blockchain like [Monero](https://www.getmonero.org/), [Zcash](https://z.cash/), or one of the many others focused on maintaining user privacy.